# bash 3rdparty/osx/install_deps.sh?

Tags: installation, apple-m1, macos-big-sur, openpose

I am trying to follow these installation instructions:

https://www.thomasvanhoey.com/post/installing-openpose-on-mac-october-2020-version/

for installing OpenPose on Mac.

I have a Mac M1, running Big Sir. When I try to do step 3, and run this in terminal: (I'm in the openpose folder that was created when I installed CMake, where there is a 3rdparty folder)

```
bash 3rdparty/osx/install_deps.sh
```

I get:

```
No such file or directory
```

also step 4 doesn't work, i run this in the command line in terminal:

```
~~protoc src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto --cpp_out=. mkdir include/caffe/proto mv src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h include/caffe/proto~~
```

I get

```
zsh: command not found: ~~protoc
```

Does anyone know why I am getting these errors? I "Cloned the repository in the target folder". I "Install CMake GUI" the old fashioned way. I ran and it installed.

```
brew install caffe
```

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Replace with: `bash scripts/osx/install_deps.sh`

The file to be executed is `install_deps.sh`. When I perform `$ find . -name osx` it is found in `openpose/scripts/`. So just run `bash scripts/osx/install_deps.sh`.